# Shortcuts for proper shutdown and reboot in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts

Which commands should I use when creating keyboard shortcuts for shutdown and reboot in Loki?

Comment: Really a non-descriptive question. What would consider "proper" other than the indicator in the top right corner that allows users to Lock, Suspend & Shutdown?

Comment: I am sorry, I edited the question. Is it descriptive now?

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the lack of description in the original question I am going to take a shot in the dark in believing you're asking how to create keyboard shortcuts for shutdown and reboot.

If this is the case, you can open System Settings->Keyboard. Then click on Shortcuts, then Custom. Here you can enter the command you wish to run then create a two key accelerator. For instance in command, I typed `reboot` then clicked on 'New accelerator' and held the Super Key and the letter 'R' which created a shortcut to reboot by holding my Super Key and hit 'R'.

Again, not sure if this was what you're looking for but this is how you create custom keyboard shortcuts.

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the commands `poweroff` and `reboot`.

Of course you can use the `shutdown` command with options, but I find the first commands simpler! :)

Comment: Thanks for following with this answer Stuart! Also, with what I've come to understand, 'poweroff' and 'reboot' are the preferred options, too. Thanks for the help!